# Accessing and uploading a file from a path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where users can upload files. I don't save the files - I use a stream and upload them to a 3rd party server. I do store the path in a database.

I now need to upload those files to a different server. So, I have a path in a database like:

```
J:\Projects\Commercial\somedoc.docx
```

and I now need to allow users to select and upload the file at that location to another server. I can't use the path in a  control - as you cannot set the value of such a control.

I am going to display a list of the file paths on a .aspx page for a user to select which files they need to upload (again, but to a different server).

How can I upload the file when all I have is a string which is the path?

Normally I would have:

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[0];
using (Stream fx = hpf.InputStream)
{
//send the stream to a remote server here
}
```

but I don't have the posted file to work with, all I have is a path.

Comment: I don't fully understand - are you saying you want a user who has already uploaded a file to be able to upload the file (whether the same or modified) from the original location on their computer?  If so, you've already answered yourself... "you cannot set the value of such a control"

Comment: Yes, they have uploaded a load of different files to Server A and now, a few weeks later, need to see a list of the files they uploaded to Server A and upload them to Server B. (It is not possible for me to copy from Server A to Server B as I don't have access to them).

Answer (score 1):

" *need to upload (again, but to a different server)* ". means you have to copy from one server to another.
So i think you have to  use **FTP** copy.

The below code may help you. The code is not tested. Please try

```
string CompleteDPath = "";
CompleteDPath = "ftp://1234.1234.12.13/Projects/Commercial";


string UName = "";
string PWD = "";
UName = "Administrator";
PWD = "12345";


WebRequest reqObj = WebRequest.Create(CompleteDPath + "somedoc.docx");
reqObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
reqObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UName, PWD);
FileStream streamObj = System.IO.File.OpenRead(physical path + "somedoc.docx");
byte[] buffer = new byte[streamObj.Length + 1];
streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
streamObj.Close();
streamObj = null;
reqObj.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqObj = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I'd have to ask the owners of Server A for permission to access the files.

Comment: yes , without `NetworkCredentials ` you cannot access files from a remote server. then FTP copy from Server A to Server B :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment...

> Yes, they have uploaded a load of different files to Server A and now, a few weeks later, need to see a list of the files they uploaded to Server A and upload them to Server B. (It is not possible for me to copy from Server A to Server B as I don't have access to them

As you have already stated, you cannot pre-select a file on a users computer - which is completely correct, as otherwise it would be a massive security hole.

If you have no ability to directly transfer the files from the Server A to Server B, then you simply have no other choice than to request the user to select those files again.

Maybe a way forward would be to list all the files they have uploaded, and provide individual upload controls for them to populate.

Be aware that there is normally a limit to the maximum "request" size that IIS will accept (which can easily be reached if uploading multiple files in a single go).  This limit can be raised through configuration, but a higher value increases the resource loading on the server

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes on the IIS issue, we are already uploading a couple of hundred MB at a time.

Comment: Ouch, you must have some impressive resources on the server to accept that from multiple users at the same time. Let us know how you solve it in the end